# Update values in another Screen - React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to update value in another screen but the onclick is is other. Check the images

**This is the screen number 1**

[image: this is the screen number 1]

**This is the screen number 2**

[image: this is screen number 2]

I want something like, when I clicked in Rui martins, I go back in page one and update the information with Rui martins data. How can I do it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you using `redux` in your app?

Comment: No. i do not use redux